# strcpy and array function char to const char problem

Tags: c, string, pointers, char

I can't give a value in a string with function. Also my strcpy is always making problem.

I have a problem in `char xc[50]=trying(c);`

> invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]

```
//This function doing reverse printing.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char trying(char *pchar);

int main()
{

char c[50]="It is a massage";

char xc[50]=trying(c);

printf("%s",xc);

return 0;

}
```

And other problem is  `char d=pchar[j-i];`

> invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]
>
> b was not declared in this scope

```
char trying(char *pchar)
{
   for(int i=0;i<strlen(pchar);i++)
   {
      int j = strlen(pchar);
    
      char b[50];
     
      char d=pchar[j-i];
    
      strcpy(b,d);
        
   }

   return b;
}
```

Comment: You say that you have problems but you don't explain what the problem is.

Comment: [Error] invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive] its for char xc[50] = trying(c);

Comment: yeah i know i'm already new in C. im using with deitel how to program c but i have just a one way to find answers. So im asking you.

Answer (score 0):

- In your `main` function, `char xc[50]=trying(c);` will not work:

To assign values to an array you'll have to do it one character at a time using a loop or using `strcpy` in case both the *source* and *destination* can be used as pointers.

- In your `trying` function, `strcpy(b,d);` will not work:

The signature of `strcpy` is `char * strcpy ( char * destination, const char * source );`
so the *source* as well as the *destination* needs to be pointers, in your case `d` is not a pointer, it is just a character + logically (not syntactically) you are copying `d` to first position of character array `b`.

Comment: okay thanks to your feedback but how can done strcpy? i changed my function block but it again made problem.

      int j = strlen(pchar);
     
   char d = pchar[j-i];
   
   char s1[50];
   
      strcpy(s1,d);

Comment: @Joseph You should first of all just focus on learning about `C` style strings and then `strcpy`. Only then you can understand whats wrong in this.